# Pandas remove characters from index

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following dataframe:

```
           A
0-1.5      1
1.5-3.3    2
3.3-5.4    3
5.4-7.9    4
```

I want to remove the '-' character with the upper value in the index so I end up with the following dataframe:

```
     A
0    1
1.5  2
3.3  3
5.4  4
```

How do I do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `split` with seelct first lists by indexing:

```
df.index = df.index.str.split('-').str[0]
```

Or use `rename` with lambda function:

```
df = df.rename(lambda x: x.split('-')[0])
```